# Windows Phone and Bluetooth LE

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to know if it is possible to list Bluetooth LE devices in Windows Phone 8? The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207007%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) comes up with a note that says that only paired devices could be listed.

Offtopic
Windows Phone really starts to freakin' me out. Every thing is hidden from the developer, like RFID, available WLAN's and so on. Sry but this had to be.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth LE support just came to some Lumia devices recently, so there are no public APIs available yet.  See [here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Introduction_to_Bluetooth_support_on_Windows_Phone_8%20here) for some details.